# How to filter filter data after extracted data in Json form

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've extracted data but having problem to filter some data that I would like to get only. Below is the code:

```
// 7. for each itemid, extract the metrics required (the list of metrics in section 2) //
      outdata.forEach(function (outJson) {
        var temp = []
        for (var j = 0; j < head.length; j++) {
          
          temp.push((outJson[head[j]]) ? outJson[head[j]] : "" ) // ? : works like an if statement (condition ? value if true : value if false) //

        }
        if(temp.length>=34){
            temp.pop() // remove the last empty column 
        }
 
        temp.push(counter)
        // console.log(temp)
        toPrint.push(temp)
        counter++
      })
    }
```

The condition that I want to filter is as below but not sure how to amend and incorporate into the above chunk to make it work:

```
temp= temp.filter(function (row) { return (row[24] ==1); })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand everything well. As far as I understand, you can simply replace

```js
temp = temp.filter(function (row) { return (row[24] ==1); })
```

by

```js
if(row[24] == 1) {
    // do stuff
}
```

And, if your aim is to, for each outdata, get the item n°24 and if, and only if, it's 1, you can simplify your code as:

```js
// Map return an array of every 24th values
// Filter return an array of only one
outdata.map((data) => data[head[24]]).filter((data) => data == 1)

// To get the number of one, you can then simply use
outdata.length
```

Comment: I think i'm thinking too much ==" Thank you

Yes this works by simply use
```if(row[24] == 1) {
    // do stuff
}```